# Carriage return has a different behavior in Eclipse and in the command prompt

Tags: python, eclipse, carriage-return

When I run the following python  3 code in the Windows command prompt or Linux terminal:

```
for i in range (10):
    print('Step {0}'.format(i), end='\r', flush=True)
print('everything is done', flush=True)
```

The output is:

```
everything is done
```

However, when I run the same code in Eclipse, the output is:

```
Step 0
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4
Step 5
Step 6
Step 7
Step 8
Step 9
everything is done
```

What could explain this?

I use Eclipse Standard/SDK, Version: Kepler Release, Build id: 20130614-0229.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Eclipse is trying to be helpful and converting \r to \r\n. This isn't surprising coming from an app like Eclipse that runs on multiple platforms.

One possible workaround is to send a lot of backspaces instead of a single \r.  (Yes that's ugly and inconvenient but it might get the job done.)  Generally speaking, overwriting console output is an iffy proposition and your results will vary depending on the context.